# Нахождение комментариев с помощью Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть файл, содержащий строки такого вида:
"ключ" "значение"

Также он содержит комментарии вида

`// текст`

Мне нужно удалить все комментарии. Для этого я использовал Regex "//[^"]*\n", но столкнулся с таким комментарием

`//"текст"`

Его регулярка не видит.
Как можно найти такой комментарий?

Выражения для проверки:

```
"ключ" "значение"

"ключ" "значение" // "всё что угодно душе и даже "коммент"

"ключ" *таб* "значение \"текст в кавычках\"" /////// коммент

"ключ"     *100500 \s*          "значение" // коммент

"ключ" "//коммент-обманочка  значение" //коммент

"ключ" "значение //коммент-обманочка" // коммент

// ПРОСТО КОММЕНТАРИЙ
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/P5TLyJ/1

Comment: Приведите однозначные примеры. Может ли быть `//текст` (без пробела), может ли в строке до комментария быть что-то ещё, могут ли в тексте быть знаки `/` и `"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше поздно, чем никогда.

*Добавил выражения для проверки в вопрос после составления ответа*

После небольших экспериментов сделал такую регулярку

```
^(\s*((\"(.*?)\")\s*((\"(.*?([^\\]))\")|(\"\"))){0,1}\s*(\/\/(.*))?)
```

С именами групп

```
^(?<all>\s*(?<parse>(?<key>\"(?<key_t>.*?)\")\s*((?<value>\"(?<value_t>.*?(?<nobackslash>[^\\]))\")|(?<emptyvalue>\"\"))){0,1}\s*(?<comment>\/\/(?<comment_t>.*))?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/3fAE8e/1

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такую регулярку: `\/\/.*?$`

[проверить](https://regex101.com/r/4acFJj/1)

Comment: `"ключ" "такое // значение"`

Comment: @aepot что это?

Comment: Поправил коммент

Comment: @aepot автор ничего не говорил про данную строку. Если надо учитывать такое - пусть напишет

Comment: ок, просто в исходнй регулярке вроде-как выфильтровываются кавычки, и мне кажется, что не просто так.